# How to print multiple array value in multiple dropdown list?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on one page where there are a lot of dropdown list and a text field from where I add a user and select some dropdown list for that user and send it into the database and it inserts successfully.. Now I want to edit that user that when I click on edit it should print all the selected dropdown in the dropdown which I selected to insert and other should remain the same.
My value is coming into the array.. I need to know how to print that array into dropdowns.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [printprofiles_id] => 1
        [profilename] => Peter
        [description] => 
        [printer] => 3
        [report_id] => 0
        [profile_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [printprofiles_id] => 2
        [profilename] => Peter
        [description] => 
        [printer] => 4
        [report_id] => 1
        [profile_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [printprofiles_id] => 3
        [profilename] => Peter
        [description] => 
        [printer] => 5
        [report_id] => 2
        [profile_id] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [printprofiles_id] => 4
        [profilename] => Peter
        [description] => 
        [printer] => 6
        [report_id] => 3
        [profile_id] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [printprofiles_id] => 5
        [profilename] => Peter
        [description] => 
        [printer] => 7
        [report_id] => 4
        [profile_id] => 1
    )

)
```

It is my Model Code

```
public function get_profilesitems_by_id($id){
$query = $this->db->get_where('setup_printprofiles', array('profile_id' => $id));
return $result = $query->result_array();

}
```

It is my Controller Code

```
public function printprofilesedit($id = 0){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('profilename', 'profilename', 'trim|required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $data['all_printers'] =  $this->setup_model->get_all_printers(); // In dropdown value is coming from another table...
                $data['all_profiles'] =  $this->setup_model->get_all_profiles();
                $data['profile'] = $this->setup_model->get_printprofiles_by_id($id);
                $data['profileitem'] = $this->setup_model->get_profilesitems_by_id($id); // In this there is an array which I showed above...
                $data['view'] = 'admin/setup/printprofilesedit';
                $this->load->view('admin/layout', $data);
            }
            else{
                $options = array(
        'report_id' => $this->input->post('report_id_'.$i),
        'printer' => $this->input->post('printer_'.$i),
        );
    $this->setup_model->edit_printprofiles($options);
}

        }
            if($options){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Record is Added Successfully!');
            redirect(base_url('admin/setup/printprofiles'));
        }
        else{
            $data['all_printers'] =  $this->setup_model->get_all_printers(); // In dropdown value is coming from another table...
            $data['all_profiles'] =  $this->setup_model->get_all_profiles();
            $data['profile'] = $this->setup_model->get_printprofiles_by_id($id);
            $data['profileitem'] = $this->setup_model->get_profilesitems_by_id($id); // In this there is an array which I showed above...
            $data['view'] = 'admin/setup/printprofilesedit';
            $this->load->view('admin/layout', $data);
        }
    }
```

Here is my printprofilesedit.php where there  is HTML Code... I showed only 4 dropdown but there are more than 50 dropdowns. As I mentioned only those dropdown should be filled which I selected at the time of insert.

```
<tr class="evenrow">
                        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id_0" id="report_id_0" value="0">0</td>
                        <td>Default printing destination</td>
                        <td>
                             <select  name="printer_0" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">

                                <option value="">Browse Support</option>

                                <?php foreach ($all_printers as $printer): ?>

                                <option value="<?= $printer['printer_id']?>"><?= $printer['name']?> </option>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr class="evenrow">
                        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id_1" id="report_id_1" value="1">1</td>
                        <td>Customer Balance</td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="printer_1" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <?php foreach ($all_printers as $printer): ?>

                                <option value="<?= $printer['printer_id']?>" ><?= $printer['name']?></option>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr class="evenrow">
                        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id_2" id="report_id_2" value="2">2</td>
                        <td>Aged Customer Analysis</td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="printer_2" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <?php foreach ($all_printers as $printer): ?>

                                <option value="<?= $printer['printer_id']?>"><?= $printer['name']?></option>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr class="evenrow">
                        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id_3" id="report_id_3" value="3">3</td>
                        <td>Customer Details Listing</td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="printer_3" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <?php foreach ($all_printers as $printer): ?>

                                <option value="<?= $printer['printer_id']?>"><?= $printer['name']?></option>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr class="evenrow">
                        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id_4" id="report_id_4" value="4">4</td>
                        <td>Price Listing</td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="printer_4" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <?php foreach ($all_printers as $printer): ?>

                                <option value="<?= $printer['printer_id']?>"><?= $printer['name']?></option>

                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: `var_dump($data['all_printers']);die;` from controller before loading the view page and see how much data you get.

Comment: 50 dropdowns???

Comment: Yes Almost 50 dropdowns